# How to copy operator definitions from amsopn.sty?

Tags: macros, amsmath, math-operators

I want to create an operator which looks exactly like one defined in the `amsmath` package.  I've found the relevant definition in amsopn.sty, but when I copy it into the preamble of my document I get an error message `Use of \varcolim doesn't match its definition`.  The code is below.

I also welcome suggestions on how better to do this.  I'd rather use a "higher level" command to create my desired symbol, but I don't like what `\newcommand\varinjcolim{\operatornamewithlimits{\underrightarrow{\mathrm{colim}}}}` produces (its spacing isn't as tight as `\varinjlim`, and I'd really like it to be identical to that except from saying "colim" instead of "lim").

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\varcolim@#1#2{%
  \vtop{\m@th\ialign{##\cr
    \hfil$#1\operator@font colim$\hfil\cr
    \noalign{\nointerlineskip\kern1.5\ex@}#2\cr
    \noalign{\nointerlineskip\kern-\ex@}\cr}}%
}
\def\varinjcolim{%
  \mathop{\mathpalette\varcolim@{\rightarrowfill@\textstyle}}\nmlimits@
}

\begin{document}

$\varinjlim$

$\varinjcolim$

\end{document}
```

Comment: you need `\makeatletter` to access commands with `@` in their name

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do